# Rust-to-rust dynamic linking equivalent of a C header (library interface)

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking

In Rust, there are two types of dynamic libraries supported.

- `cdylib` - that creates a "C interface" (kind of like `extern "C"` in C++), to be used by C or anything that can use C FFI. `cbindgen` can be used to create C headers from Rust sources.
- `dylib` - Rust dynamic library, contains the mangled function name, and a `.rustc` metadata section that might contain some other useful bits as well (is there a tool to parse and display this?).

Is there something like a "header" for `dylib`, or does the full source need to be included when linking with a dynamic library. If the full source does need to be included, that somewhat defeats the purpose of dynamic linking, no?

I am aware rustc would need to be of the same version (ABI is not stable, but might be stabilised in future: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/repr-interoperable-2024/16763). I am also aware of solutions such as https://docs.rs/abi_stable/latest/abi_stable/ (which could be used for plugins even across different rustc versions).

Related: [Dynamic linking between crates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903098/dynamic-linking-between-crates/75903553)

Comment: Are you asking about linking Rust to a C dynamic library, C to a rust dynamic library, or rust to rust?  I'm not 100% sure based on context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Rust allow distributing closed-source libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183630/does-rust-allow-distributing-closed-source-libraries)

Comment: @cafce25 Not really. I am happy using the same compiler version, but the lack of interface files could be a problem (although ... for example in Java one can use reflection to discover classes, methods, types). If it's not possible, I guess the first question is what's the point of having `dylib` at all.

Comment: tl;dr from my answer there "and there are no interface files" that's a header from C-land so the short answer is no. The point of a dynamic library is to enable code reuse in memory, that's not prohibited at all.

Comment: Fair enough, that was how I worded it. Care to make it an answer and include a reference to "no interface files"?

Comment: Technically there are `extern "Rust" { ... }` blocks that could act kinda like an interface file. Depends on what exactly you need. The only place I've seen them used is the standard library: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/alloc.rs.html#20-43

Comment: Here's an `extern "Rust"` example, but I haven't tested it with an actual external library: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a1ab4b85a3a14c2aeb4adf55233a24e

Comment: @PitaJ, I can make your way work with separate project (lib + main), and it only requires .so, no source code. However, `extern "Rust"` seems to work pretty much like `extern "C"` - there is no module name etc. encoded in the symbol name.

Comment: Yeah if you need namespacing you will need to do that manually.